# Jersey - Jackson - JSON - Date format

Tags: json, jaxb, jersey, jackson

I am trying to to configure the date format returned from the serialized JSON object of Jersey WS as below:

```
@Component
@Provider
@Produces("application/json")
public class JacksonContextResolver implements ContextResolver<ObjectMapper> {

    private ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

    public JacksonContextResolver() {
        mapper.setDateFormat(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd"));
    }

    @Override
    public ObjectMapper getContext(Class<?> arg0) {
        return mapper;
    }
}
```

But the problem is that **getContext(Class arg0)** method is not get invoked. Only the constructor **JacksonContextResolver()** is invoked.

However the following ContextResolver of JAXB is working fine:

```
@Component
@Provider
public class JAXBContextResolver implements ContextResolver<JAXBContext> {

    private JAXBContext context;
    private Class<?>[] types = { 
            UserDto.class, AttachmentDto.class
    };

    public JAXBContextResolver() throws Exception {
        this.context = new JSONJAXBContext(JSONConfiguration.natural().rootUnwrapping(false).build(), types);
    }

    public JAXBContext getContext(Class<?> objectType) {
        return context;
    }
}
```

Could anyone advise if there are any missing configuration?

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't get the ContextResolver to work for me either, but I found this blog which did work:

http://blog.seyfi.net/2010/03/how-to-control-date-formatting-when.html